# Firebase analytics - content_type is blank or (not set)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am trying to record event parameters for `select_content` event in Firebase. I believe I've set everything up correctly, and I can see events with parameters in the **last 30 minutes** card in the dashboard. However, I cannot see any parameter stats in the **Content** card. I was fiddling with it yesterday, but all I would get is `(not_set)` in that card; now I can't even see that. How can I view the stats for all parameters for a specific event?

I couldn't find any answers on SO that helped me out.

[image]

```
fun logScreenView(name: String) {
    Bundle().apply {
        putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, name)
        putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, name)
        putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, name)
    }
        .also { firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, it) }
}
```

Comment: Did you register your event parameters in Firebase console?

Comment: Same here. Yet not find any answer on this. Some events have blank parameters, some events have (not set) but many more events have specified name. Don't know why blank or (not set)